# How to get info or actual of short URL service without redirect on original

Tags: php

I have created shortened URL of https://www.google.com.

I have used a URL shortener to shorten of about converted link

Now when I click on the shortened links, they will redirect me to https://www.google.com.

1. How to know the final link from a shortened link using PHP without redirection to Google.com in above case?
2. How to get number of redirection (for recursive shorten URL) without going to original/final link using PHP?

Comment: Both questions are possible with cURL.

Comment: dear glavic, thanks for reply. any example or url?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/curl_getinfo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even easier solution would be to set curl only to fetch headers (*ignore body*), and follow locations; and then use `curl_getinfo()` function to fetch last url and no. of redirects:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
));
curl_exec($ch);
$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$redirect_count = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now you have variables :

- `$last_url` = last URL in the redirect loop
- `$redirect_count` = no. of redirects that happened

Take a look [at other great `curl_getinfo()` parameters](https://www.php.net/curl_getinfo) you can fetch.

p.s. you can set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` to see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Follow HTTP responses until you reach response code different than 301.

You can get HTTP response code and next url like this:

```
$http = curl_init($url);
$result = curl_exec($http);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$next_url = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
curl_close($http);
echo $http_status;
echo $next_url;
```

Comment: Thanks harri!! will it help to show recursive shorten url as above?

Comment: You need to wrap that in a while loop which ends when $http_status is not 301. Also, keep increasing some variable to get the count of how many redirects there were.

Comment: @Newbie123: if you found an answer (or question) useful on SO, don't forget to upvote it.